# error while running command ./catalina.sh run in cygdrive

Tags: cygwin

Anila@Annie /cygdrive/c/server/c1/apache/bin
$ ./catalina.sh run

Using CLASSPATH:       C:\server\c1\apache\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\server\c1\apache\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
./catalina.sh: line 319: /c/server/c1/jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory

this the error i get when i tried running it when implementing cluster and load balancing with apache. what to do?

Comment: Is `catalina.sh` is a homemade script ? What is the content of line 319 ? Check your PATH to see is there is a `/c/server/c1/jdk/bin/java` in it, if so change to `/cygdrive/c/server/c1/jdk/bin/java`.

Comment: i tried that but the  error still persists.